# Batch file that unzips and combines contents

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to unzip some folders and then recombine them, however when I run the batch file it get the following error:

> 'unzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I am guessing I need to point the batch file to where 7-zip is correct? Any insight would be appreciated thanks!

See below for code:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
:unzip
echo.
echo Unzipping files
echo.
unzip ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_2of5.zip
unzip ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_3of5.zip
unzip ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_4of5.zip
unzip ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_5of5.zip


echo.
:combining
echo.
echo Combining parts
echo.
copy /b ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_1of4+ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_2of4+ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_3of4+ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_4of4 ELMDB-85308-PI003.OVA
:done
echo.
echo Done!
echo.
pause
:end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `unzip` as a command, try `7z -e`.

If you copy `7z.exe` to some directory that is on your PATH, then you don't need to specify the directory.

You can see your PATH by executing

```
PATH
```

from the prompt. This displays a <kbd>;</kbd>-separated list of directories that are searched after the current directory) for executables.

If `7z.exe` is not on your PATH, then you'd need

```
"c:\wherever\it is\7z" -e ....
```

---

(more explaining)

If `7z` is in your path, then

```
7Z -e ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_2of5.zip
```

will unzip `ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_2of5.zip`

And you'd then need to add a line for each of the other files (which you have done).

If `7z.exe` is **not** on your path then you need

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" -e ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_2of5.zip
```

and reproduce *that* for each of your files.

You can tell that `7z.exe` is in your path by executing `7z` from the prompt. You will get either a report stating that it's not recognised (ie it's **not** on your path) or you'll get a commands-and-switches help report (which means it **is** on your path)

Since the command `7z` did not work, then it's not on your path, so you need the other form.

If you were to `copy /b C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"`c:\windows\system32\" then in all probability you'd have `7z.exe` on your path and hence you could use the short form.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I updated the batch file like so: @echo off
cls
:start
:7Z -e
echo.
echo Unzipping files
echo.

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" -e

7Z -e ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_2of5.zip
7Z -e ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_3of5.zip
7Z -e ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_4of5.zip
7Z -e ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_5of5.zip

echo.
:combining
echo.
echo Combining parts
echo.
copy /b ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_1of4+ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_2of4+ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_3of4+ELMDB-85308-PI003_OVA_4of4 ELMDB-85308-PI003.OVA
:done
echo.
echo Done!
echo.
pause
:end

Comment: Sorry I am probably doing this wrong, but I wanted to say I updated it with the code above but am still getting an the same error.